# Validation error: "Attribute readonly not allowed on element input at this point."

Tags: html, validation

When I try to validate the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>test page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="testInput" value="test value" readonly="readonly" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;">
    </body>
</html>
```

[The validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) gives the error:

```
Line 8, Column 118: Attribute readonly not allowed on element input at this point.
```

But in the error details it says:

```
readonly when type is text, ...
```

As this is a text input, why am I receiving the validation error?

Comment: I'm wondering if it is a bug in the validator, as `search` and `email` work just fine. WHATWG confirms that `readonly` is valid here; it also states that `text` and `search` are nearly [identical functionally](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#text-(type=text)-state-and-search-state-(type=search)), leading me to question further why the W3's validator would accept `search` but not `text`.

Comment: Yes, this is a bug. The http://validator.nu/ validator (which is based on the same code base) does not have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is bug in the W3C Markup Validator; I have submitted a [bug report](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=21708).

While waiting for the bug to be fixed (which I expect to happen soon), use the [validator.nu](http://validator.nu/) service instead.

***Update:*** The bug has now been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

`readonly` attribute is only allowed on these input types:

- text
- search
- url
- tel
- email
- password
- date
- month
- week
- time
- datetime-local
- number

For any other input type like `hidden`, you are not allowed to have `readonly` in which case you may get:

> Error: Attribute readonly not allowed on element input at this point.